# Beginner PHP Question - Access Data from Function

Tags: php

I have this function:

```
function selectValue($test) {
    $connection = dbConnect(HOST, USERNAME, PASSWORD, DATABASE);
    $query = "SELECT * FROM table where value = '$test'";
    $results = @mysql_query($query, $connection);   
    $value = mysql_fetch_assoc($results);
}

selectValue('abcde');

echo $value['something'];
```

This results in $value becoming an array. I would like to access this array from outside of the function.  I tried to do this using the last line of code above (ie. echo...) but this doesn't work.  How should I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
function selectValue($test) {
$connection = dbConnect(HOST, USERNAME, PASSWORD, DATABASE);
    $query = "SELECT * FROM table where value = '$test'";
    $results = @mysql_query($query, $connection);   
    $value = mysql_fetch_assoc($results);
return $value;
}


$value = selectValue('abcde');

echo $value['something'];
```

Comment: lol just as i pressed post, 5 answers all basically the same where up, toooo slow fingers :)

Answer (score 7):

You need to [return a value](http://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.returning-values.php) from your function:

```
function selectValue($test) {
    $connection = dbConnect(HOST, USERNAME, PASSWORD, DATABASE);
    $query = "SELECT * FROM pans where value = '$test'";
    $results = @mysql_query($query, $connection);   
    $value = mysql_fetch_assoc($results);
    return $value;
}


$value = selectValue('abcde');

echo $value['something'];
```

Be aware that the function could fail at various places, so you should not always assume that the return value will contain the result from `mysql_fetch_assoc`.

One way to do that (one way of many) is to test the return value before using it:

```
function selectValue($test) {
    $value = false;
    $connection = dbConnect(HOST, USERNAME, PASSWORD, DATABASE);
    $query = "SELECT * FROM pans where value = '$test'";
    $results = @mysql_query($query, $connection);   
    $value = mysql_fetch_assoc($results);
    return $value;
}    

if($value = selectValue('abcde')) {
    echo $value['something'];
} else {
    echo "Something went wrong.\n";
}
```

[Exception handling](http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php) is another way to handle errors.

Answer (score 2):

Put the `return` keyword in your function:

```
function selectValue($test) {
$connection = dbConnect(HOST, USERNAME, PASSWORD, DATABASE);
    $query = "SELECT * FROM pans where value = '$test'";
    $results = @mysql_query($query, $connection);   
    $value = mysql_fetch_assoc($results);
    return $value; // return the value
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can return value from the function - here I rewrote it for you:

```
function selectValue($test) {
    $connection = dbConnect(HOST, USERNAME, PASSWORD, DATABASE);
    $query = "SELECT * FROM pans where value = '$test'";
    $results = @mysql_query($query, $connection);   
    $value = mysql_fetch_assoc($results);

    return $value;
}


$val = selectValue('abcde');

echo $val['something'];
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have already defined $value outside that function? Otherwise you need to return it so you can access it outside the function.

Answer (score 0):

return the value

```
return $value
```

or use `globals`. but globals are not state of the art anymore and shouldn't be used.

Answer (score -2):

This may help

```
<?php
$a = 1;
$b = 2;

function Sum()
{
    global $a, $b;

    $b = $a + $b;
} 

Sum();
echo $b;
?>
```

Comment: Using globals in this fashion is bad practice